# getThis() trick and ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics

I've been wondering about the `getThis()` trick, and the alternative of the unsafe cast from a self-bounded type to its type parameter.

```
public abstract class SelfBound<T extends SelfBound<T>> {
    protected abstract T getThis();

    public void doSomething(T instance) { ... }
    public final void doSomethingWithThis() { doSomething(getThis()); }
    public final void doSomethingWithThisUnsafe() { doSomething((T) this); }
}
```

Is it possible to subclass `SelfBound` such that `doSomethingWithThisUnsafe()` throws a `ClassCastException`?  (Is it possible to do this without subclassing `SelfBound`?)

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your question. Just return some nonsense value of a type that doesn't extend `SelfBound` but that might have.

Comment: For example, we can have `Serializable val = new Serializable() {}; return (SomeSubclass) val;` inside the overriden `getThis()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis he wants to know if there's a way to choose `T` in so that `doSomethingWithThisUnsafe` throws a CCE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely it's possible to have `ClassCastException` with subclassing. Here's a simple example:

```
public abstract class SelfBound<T extends SelfBound<T>> {
    protected abstract T getThis();

    public void doSomething(T instance) { }
    public final void doSomethingWithThis() { doSomething(getThis()); }
    public final void doSomethingWithThisUnsafe() { doSomething((T) this); }

    public static class A extends SelfBound<A> {
        @Override
        protected A getThis() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class B extends SelfBound<A> {
        @Override
        public void doSomething(A instance) {
            super.doSomething(instance);
        }

        @Override
        protected A getThis() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().doSomethingWithThisUnsafe();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: SelfBound$B cannot be cast to SelfBound$A
    at SelfBound$B.doSomething(SelfBound.java:1)
    at SelfBound.doSomethingWithThisUnsafe(SelfBound.java:6)
    at SelfBound.main(SelfBound.java:28)
```

It's not so clear what do you mean by "without subclassing `SelfBound`". As `SelfBound` is an abstract class, you cannot call its methods without subclassing it, thus you cannot have any exception when calling its methods.